# WiFi Range Extenders, and Failing ARP requests

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ping, arp

I'm working on a network, as outlined below - a BT HomeHub 5, and a Netgear EX6150 WiFi extender. There are other points on the network though I've left them out for brevity, and all of the pink dashed lines are WiFi.

[image: network diagram]

The problem I'm seeing is that PC 1 *cannot* (*will not*) communicate with PC 2, but my phone *will*. Of course my phone has the ability to hop over and connect to the extender directly, and I can't currently rule that out as playing a part here.

The same situation stands for PC 1 trying to communicate with other hosts on the WiFi extender.

All hosts have access to the internet.

---

I have discovered that the extender will "*munge*" MAC addresses, but I'm not quite able to figure out *why*. For example, PC 2's MAC address is `88:b1:11:f4:e0:66`, but the router's interface (and hosts connected to the router) will see it communicate as `02:0f:b5:f4:e0:66`. There is a terribly written section in the [manual](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/EX6150/EX6150_UM_EN.pdf) on [page 33](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pqyfk.png), and there doesn't appear to be a way to turn it off. I cannot see any technical reason for this, and I'm currently placing my bet on this being a key part of the issue.

---

Time for technical bits.

- PC 1 is `192.168.1.74` / `1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08` (as reported by the OS)
- PC 2 is `192.168.1.16` / `88:b1:11:f4:e0:66` (as reported by the OS)

My phone will merrily scan the network (using [Fing](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.overlook.android.fing&hl=en_GB)), discover the host, and ping it... as mentioned before, PC 1 will not.

I've tried adding PC 2's address information to PC 1's ARP table by hand:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>netsh interface ip add neighbors 14 192.168.1.16 02-0f-b5-f4-e0-66


C:\WINDOWS\system32>arp -a

Interface: 192.168.1.74 --- 0xe
  Internet Address      Physical Address      Type
  ...
  192.168.1.16          02-0f-b5-f4-e0-66     static
  ...

C:\WINDOWS\system32>ping 192.168.1.16

Pinging 192.168.1.16 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.
Request timed out.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.16:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

So this is clearly not *just* an ARP issue.

Looking at this from PC 2's perspective, I've taken a `tcpdump` during a ping:

```
$ tcpdump -enr dump.cap
11:37:45.730405 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1317, length 40
11:37:45.730468 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.74 tell 192.168.1.16, length 28
11:37:45.764667 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.74 is-at 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, length 28
11:37:45.764678 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66 > 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.16 > 192.168.1.74: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1317, length 40
```

There is no `who-has` before the ICMP echo request, as we've laid that out by hand... but PC 2 clearly responds with an echo reply to `1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08` after a successful ARP query - good stuff - but PC 1 claims to never receive it.

Additionally, after the ping, PC 2 has PC 1's address in its ARP table (I removed it before):

```
$ arp -n
Address                  HWtype  HWaddress           Flags Mask            Iface
...
192.168.1.74             ether   1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08   C                     wlp3s0
...
```

---

Repeating a ping with Wireshark on PC 1, and `tcpdump` on PC 2 reveals the following (see below for the dumps):

- Traffic from PC 1 → PC 2 appears to be fine

  - There is no MAC munging of the source
- Traffic from PC 2 → PC 1 is only received if it's a broadcast (e.g: the ARP request)

  - There *is* MAC munging of the source

#### PC 1

```
$ tcpdump -enr pc1_dump4.cap
reading from file pc1_dump4.cap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
12:17:59.525610 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 02:0f:b5:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1330, length 40
12:17:59.641049 02:0f:b5:f4:e0:66 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.74 tell 192.168.1.16, length 28
12:17:59.641080 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 02:0f:b5:f4:e0:66, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.74 is-at 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, length 28
12:18:04.345340 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 02:0f:b5:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1331, length 40
12:18:09.346886 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 02:0f:b5:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1332, length 40
12:18:14.347539 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 02:0f:b5:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1333, length 40
```

#### PC 2

```
$ tcpdump -enr pc2_dump4.cap
reading from file dump4.cap, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet)
12:18:02.206931 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1330, length 40
12:18:02.206995 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66 > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Request who-has 192.168.1.74 tell 192.168.1.16, length 28
12:18:02.289242 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66, ethertype ARP (0x0806), length 42: Reply 192.168.1.74 is-at 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, length 28
12:18:02.289254 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66 > 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.16 > 192.168.1.74: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1330, length 40
12:18:07.122444 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1331, length 40
12:18:07.122484 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66 > 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.16 > 192.168.1.74: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1331, length 40
12:18:12.037691 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1332, length 40
12:18:12.037729 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66 > 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.16 > 192.168.1.74: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1332, length 40
12:18:17.170982 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08 > 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.74 > 192.168.1.16: ICMP echo request, id 1, seq 1333, length 40
12:18:17.171025 88:b1:11:f4:e0:66 > 1c:3e:84:c8:0c:08, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), length 74: 192.168.1.16 > 192.168.1.74: ICMP echo reply, id 1, seq 1333, length 40
```

---

If I reverse the direction (PC 2 sends echo requests to PC 1), then PC 1 never sees the request.

Disabling the Windows firewall doesn't help.

As a last resort, connecting PC 1 to the router by Ethernet resolves the issue... however this is not currently an acceptable solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: As a follow up, this appears to no longer be a problem... Things appear to be working normally (aside from the MAC munging).